# Recycler view items height issue on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a recycler view and items in it vary in height and it also has multiple view types. When a new item is added at position 0 it retains height of item that previously held the place.

Comment: Can you post more details, your code and image with problem.

Comment: Will post code, Actually I have a recycler view. It adds comments and it is reversed. New comments are added at 0th positionComments length may vary so does each child heights. if i add a lengthy comment is added and followed by a shorter one it takes height of last visible items height